# How to convert nested object to nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, pydantic

I have an object `Entry` with following fields as id, scene_info and rating. As can be seen, the object has attributes that are types to other classes `Scene` and `Item`. I want to convert this object to dictionary.

```
Entry(id=None, scene_info=Scene(Recipes=[Item(ID='rec.chicky-nuggies', SpawnerIdx=0), Item(ID='rec.impossible-burger', SpawnerIdx=1)], Decor=[Item(ID='dec.plate-large-orange', SpawnerIdx=2), Item(ID='dec.plate-small-green', SpawnerIdx=3)]), rating=None)
(Pdb) vars(self)
{'id': None, 'scene_info': Scene(Recipes=[Item(ID='rec.chicky-nuggies', SpawnerIndex=0), Item(ID='rec.impossible-burger', SpawnerIdx=1)], Decor=[Item(ID='dec.plate-large-orange', SpawnerIdx=2), Item(ID='dec.plate-small-green', SpawnerIdx=3)]), 'rating': None}
```

`EXPECTED RESULT`

```
{'id': None, 'scene_info':{'Recipes': [{'ID': 'rec.chicky-nuggies', 'SpawnerIdx': 0}, {'ID': 'rec.impossible-burger', 'SpawnerIdx': 1}], 'Decor': [{'ID': 'dec.plate-large-orange', 'SpawnerIndex': 2}, {'ID': 'dec.plate-small-green', 'SpawnerIdx': 3}]}, 'rating': None}
```

I tried `vars` and they only convert outer object to dict but not inner object. How can I convert the nested ones?

Comment: Pydantic models have [model.dict(...)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way:

```py
class Bar:
    # child class
    # some init code...

    def encode(self):
        return vars(self)

class Foo:
    # parent class
    # some init code...

    def encode(self):
        return vars(self)

    def to_json(self, indent=None):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.encode(), indent=indent)
```

`to_json()` will give  you a json string for the class and its nested objects if they are simple enough, you can also use marshmallow to do this with more control. You could just do `return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: vars(o), indent=indent)` in the parent class and not have the `encode()` method but using the `encode` method allows you to customize the output.

Here is some random, silly code to show how it might be used and the output:

```py
import json


class Ingredient:
    def __init__(self, name, cost=0):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost

    def encode(self):
        return vars(self)


class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, name, prep_time=0, cook_time=0, ingredients=None,
                 instructions=None):
        self.name = name
        self.prep_time = prep_time
        self.cook_time = cook_time
        self.ingredients = ingredients or []
        self.instructions = instructions or {}

    def encode(self):
        return vars(self)

    def to_json(self, indent=None):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.encode(), indent=indent)


lettuce = Ingredient('Lettuce', 1.3)
tomato = Ingredient('Tomato', 5.2)

salad = Recipe('Salad', prep_time=5, cook_time=0)

salad.ingredients = [
    lettuce,
    tomato
]

salad.instructions = {
    'Step 1': 'Get the ingredients out',
    'Step 2': 'Mix tem together',
    'Step 3': 'Eat' 
}

print(salad.to_json(4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "name": "Salad",
    "prep_time": 5,
    "cook_time": 0,
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "name": "Lettuce",
            "cost": 1.3
        },
        {
            "name": "Tomato",
            "cost": 5.2
        }
    ],
    "instructions": {
        "Step 1": "Get the ingredients out",
        "Step 2": "Mix tem together",
        "Step 3": "Eat"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefered way to go would be using modifing class definition as stated by [Tenacious B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12442479/tenacious-b), but if you want a fast solution you can use the *recursive* function stated below.

```
def class2dict(instance, built_dict={}):
    if not hasattr(instance, "__dict__"):
        return instance
    new_subdic = vars(instance)
    for key, value in new_subdic.items():
        new_subdic[key] = class2dict(value)
    return new_subdic
```

**Example:**

```
# Class definitions
class Scene:
    def __init__(self, time_dur, tag):
        self.time_dur = time_dur
        self.tag = tag


class Movie:
    def __init__(self, scene1, scene2):
        self.scene1 = scene1
        self.scene2 = scene2


class Entry:
    def __init__(self, movie):
        self.movie = movie
```

```py
In [2]: entry = Entry(Movie(Scene('1 minute', 'action'), Scene('2 hours', 'comedy')))                                                                                                                                                                                       
In [3]: class2dict(entry)                                                                                                             
Out[3]:                                                                                                                          
{'movie': {
    'scene1': {'time_dur': '1 minute', 'tag': 'action'},                                                                         
    'scene2': {'time_dur': '2 hours', 'tag': 'comedy'}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pydantic model's `Entry.json()`, this will convert everything including nested models to a string which can then be converted back to a dictionary by using something like `json.loads()`

Answer (score 0):

For the class types (Entry\Scene\Item), you can create a function the returns the arguments as a dictionary.

Try this code:

```
def getargs(**kwargs):
   return kwargs  # already a dictionary

Entry = Scene = Item = getargs  # all functions do same thing

x = Entry(id=None, scene_info=Scene(Recipes=[Item(ID='rec.chicky-nuggies', SpawnerIdx=0), Item(ID='rec.impossible-burger', SpawnerIdx=1)], Decor=[Item(ID='dec.plate-large-orange', SpawnerIdx=2), Item(ID='dec.plate-small-green', SpawnerIdx=3)]), rating=None)

print(x)
```

Output

```
{'id': None, 'scene_info': {'Recipes': [{'ID': 'rec.chicky-nuggies', 'SpawnerIdx': 0}, {'ID': 'rec.impossible-burger', 'SpawnerIdx': 1}], 'Decor': [{'ID': 'dec.plate-large-orange', 'SpawnerIdx': 2}, {'ID': 'dec.plate-small-green', 'SpawnerIdx': 3}]}, 'rating': None}
```